# Left join multiple rows

Tags: sql, join, left-join

I have the following tables:

[image: Tables]

I'd like to join the two tables so I can list each farm on the farm table alongside each product on the produce table, but I'm not sure how. This is what I've got so far:

```
SELECT p.*, f.farm_name, f.county
FROM produce p
LEFT JOIN farms f on p.farm_id = f.id
GROUP by f.id
ORDER BY f.farm_name
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT p.*
FROM produce p
inner join farms f on p.farm_id = f.id
```

in your `php` fetching code do like this,

```
$row["farm_name"];
```

It will return farm name with every produce row.

Comment: Ah yes, I shouldn't have grouped it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Former versions of SQL standards (SQL-92 and earlier) **do not permit** queries with the `SELECT` `HAVING` or`ORDER BY` clause refer to non-aggregated columns that are not named in the `GROUP BY` clause. If you look back at your original query you will see that your query does exactly what those standards do not permit.

```
SELECT p.*, f.farm_name, f.county
...
GROUP BY f.id
```

*"non-aggregating column" means any column not using an aggregate function such as sum() count() avg() and so on*

To make your query comply with those standards every column listed under select would be specified in that group by clause, not just one. MySQL has a feature that allows you to run a non-compliant style of grouping query. Had it instead informed you that query was improper syntax you would probably have realised group by isn't helping you here.

This indicates you are using MySQL, and that you do not have the SQL Mode `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` on.

I urge you to avoid this MySQL weakness, turn the SQL Mode `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` on.

See:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html

Comment: Your first paragraph is not entirely true any more with more recent versions of the SQL standard. If the GROUP BY contains a column that all others in the SELECT list are functional dependent on (e.g. grouping by the PK), the SQL standard does allow to leave out those functional dependent columns from the group by

Comment: The statement is true as I specify which standards I am referring to. It is also true that more recent versions of the SQL standard, through "functional dependence", allows optional listing of columns, I chose to omit this to simplify the fundamental message. nb: I have slightly modified the first sentence to be more explicit.